# Magento Soap V2 catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes not being recognized.

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I am reading magnetos documentation and in there they have a section that shows how to retrieve a products additional attributes.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.listOfAdditionalAttributes.html

One of the examples they show is the following for Soap V2...

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes($sessionId, 'simple', '13');
var_dump($result);
```

Well I tried that example and I get a soap error. that says the following

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes") is not a valid method for this service
```

I looked up the method in wsdl xml page and I couldn't find anything that remotely matched it.  So is the documentation out dated ?? Is my wsdl out date or whats going on here ? I am using v2

Comment: Which version of Magento do you work on? Your example works fine on 1.7, the documentation is up-to-date. Please check if your wsdl is cached (Configuration/Services/Magento Core API/Use wsdl cache), and your api user has access to the resources (API Roles)

Comment: This API call is definitely missing in the WSDL for Soap V2 on Magento ver 1.13.1.0 yet it is STILL in the documentation.  It is not a cache or access issue.  I presume the Magento devs removed this to fit more accurately into the CatalogProductAttribute call sets that you have below but forgot to update the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
$attributeList = $fclient->catalogProductAttributeList($fsession, $prod->set);
```

The above give you additional and core attributes. Where $prod->set is the products attribute set number.

And even better. if you want to get ALL of a certain products attributes values, you can do the following

```
        foreach($attributeList as $attr) {
            $attributes->additional_attributes[] = $attr->code;
        }
        $prodInfo = $fclient->catalogProductInfo($fsession, $prod->product_id, null,$attributes);
```

The above will return back all of a products attribute's values both core and custom within additional attributes.

Comment: Have you ever found a way to get product info to return all the attributes without first enumerating them into the additional attributes array?  Seems like a simple wildcard approach would be ideal, but I've tried all the combinations I can think of.  Sometimes I just need a quick product call with all attributes and making two calls is not ideal and I can't always cache the attribute list ahead of time.